# Are all intermediate growth branch groups just-infinite?

Tags: geometric-group-theory, subgroup-growth

Are all branch groups of intermediate growth just-infinite? I can't seem to find an answer to this one way or another; the question is motivated by the fact all examples of intermediate growth branch groups I know being just-infinite, and by [this paper by Nekrashevych](https://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Enekrash/Preprints/dendrites.pdf) in which he constructs a family of branch groups, all but one of which are just-infinite and intermediate growth and one being neither.

[This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510294.pdf) paper by Bartholdi, Grigorchuk and Sunic is my main reference on branch groups so far.

Comment: Crosspost to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363419/

Answer (score 1):

All **known** branch groups of intermediate growth are just infinite. That means your question is still open.